# Simple Circuits

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, power

I have a small and easy dilemma, judging by how sophisticated the website is, and need a simple answer for it

So $P=E/t$.
And $P=I*V$.
Therefore $E/t=I*V$.

I just need an explanation on how this is possible and an example to help me understand.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The third equation follows from the first two simply by inserting the first into the second. What do you want to know?

Comment: The third equation follows the first two because the power value is the same. I want to know why that is and how it is possible

Comment: It seems that your question has more to do with the units of measurement.  The equations you posted are merely illustrating that quantities such as Power, Voltage, Energy, Time, etc. can be measured in different units.  The first equation says that the units of Power are the same as the units of energy divided by time (e.g. Joules per second).  The second equation $P=IV$ merely says that Power can also be defined as voltage times current or the units of Volt-Amperes.  We could get esoteric and end up defining units have have no practical use but are indeed correct.

Comment: I see that maybe I have stated such but what I meant to be coming across is the relation between each unit of measurement. Power is measured under WATTS in the end but I just wanted to know how Voltage times Current will be equal to Energy divided by Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'll write the energy with the letter $U$ to not confuse with the electric field $E$.

By definition of power, $P=\frac{dU}{dt}$. Now, where is this energy in the equation coming from?
$$U=\int \vec{F}\cdot \vec{dl} = q \int \vec{E}\cdot \vec{dl} = qV$$
This is the amount of energy gained by the charge when moving across an electric potential differenct $V$. Because of its collisions in the resistor it gets out of it with the same kinetic energy (on average), so the collisions produced heat in the resistor, and $qV$ energy was "wasted". Now remember that in a time $dt$, the amount of charges that passed through the resistor is $q=Idt$. How much energy turned into heat in that time? $IV dt$

The conclusion is that $P=\frac{dU}{dt}=IV$.

Answer (score 1):

First equation: power is defined as energy per unit time.

Second equation: if a current flows through a circuit, the power dissipated is the product of voltage and current. This is because the voltage describes the energy each electron is given to traverse the circuit, and the current describes the number of electrons that travel the circuit per unit time. The product:

$$\frac{Energy}{unit\ charge}\times\frac{charge}{second}$$ give you the total energy per unit time. And that is your third equation.